# Magento Query slow

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have code for generating sku numbers that looks for gaps in the existing sku table using this query.

```
SELECT t1.sku 
FROM catalog_product_entity t1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS t2 ON CAST( t2.sku AS UNSIGNED ) = CAST( t1.sku AS UNSIGNED ) +1
WHERE t2.sku IS NULL 
AND CAST( t1.sku AS UNSIGNED ) >100000
ORDER BY CAST( t1.sku AS UNSIGNED ) ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Without the Ordery By it takes a little under a second. With the order by it takes about a minute. Is there a way to optimize the query to load faster?

Table Build:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity` (  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',  
`entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type ID',  
`attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set ID',  
`type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'simple' COMMENT 'Type ID',  
`sku` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SKU',  
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time',  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Update Time',  `has_options` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Has Options',  `required_options` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Required Options',  `absolute_price` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  `absolute_weight` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` (`attribute_set_id`),  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_SKU` (`sku`),  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14950 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Table'
```

Comment: can you add the output of `explain t1` and `explain t2` ? do you have indexes (primary / secondary keys?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAST is the killer.

If you want to do arithmetic on numbers and use INDEXes, store the values as numbers.

```
ON function(indexed_column) ...
```

cannot use the index on that column.  Ditto in WHERE clauses.

The ORDER BY had to find all the possible rows and sort them before delivering a row (LIMIT 1).  The JOIN had to completely scan each the second table for each row in the first table, so that took a really long time.

Without the ORDER BY, only one such scan was needed before satisfying the LIMIT 1.  Hence it was deceptively fast.  (But not as fast as it would have been if `sku` were declared INT or BIGINT and you removed the CASTs.)

Comment: I ended up doing a simple query and then iterating through it with PHP. Way faster now;.